# Partition table unrecognized on gParted, shown wrong in Disks

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I had dual boot on my old laptop (2006), with win XP and Ubuntu 13.04 witch was installed after the XP, and everything worked well for me.

So, as per usual, I decided to re-install my XP, witch actually halfway crashed with some "random error"... Anyway, I can live without it (almost)...

After rebooting, I found out that the GRUB or/and MBR is gone (messed up). I managed to rescue these with the Ubuntu live-CD and big help from AskUbuntu community. Yet, the thing are not the same as before...

[image: unallocated HDD] - HDD shown as entirely unallocated, information about unallocated.

Due to my state of Newbie, I can't even describe the problem well, so uploading some pictures so you can see what I have.

I would lie to have more space on my primary Linux partition, but before that - I want my partition table to be recognized, as well as to cease the overlap of the partitions...

[image: Disks] - no partition 3, it's a content of a extended partition 2.

Please ask for more info as needed, I'll try my best to gather it for you, on a same way I'm discovering and learning Ubuntu.

Any thought is appreciated. Thank you.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This is what I see after run `sudo fdisk -lu`

**Terminal**

```
omitting empty partition (5)
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5e6e6c09

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    78482484    39241211    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        78483454   312560639   117038593    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda3       107780148   312560639   102390246    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5        78483456   105826303    13671424   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       105828352   107780095      975872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partition table is corrupt because sda3 and sda2 overlap.  I suggest using fdisk to delete sda5 and sda6 ( which live inside sda2 ), then delete sda2, and recreate it so that it does not overlap with sda3, then you should be able to recreate sda5 and sda6 with the same start and end sectors to avoid data loss.

Comment: Firs of all, thank you for your answer. I still can't understand how/why is this all came to be this like... Anyway. _Stupid Windows!_ :D
I have been trying to understand well the steps I would need to take and in general whats going on with my partitions. I am kind a scared to touch the `sda5` because its where my **Ubuntu** is, alongside with `sda6` (swap). Then the `sda3` is all my personal stuff, use to be "D:" on win. And all these 3 partitions (sda3, sda5 and sda6) is inside the `sda2`. Should I buy an external HDD to backup everything I have? And what could I use the `sda1` for??

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis, You should *always* have backups of data you care about because sooner or later, you will lose it somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will backup as soon as possible. A little thing more, can I just delete **all** the partitions and create just one for Ubuntu + Swap, and the second for my data? Would it be better to keep all my partitions as a primary (not extended)?

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis, if you want to totally reformat the drive and restore from backup, sure.  I was trying to suggest a way to fix the problem without messing up your existing data.

Comment: well that could be really nice. If you could just provide for me some guide or a 'step by step', I will immediately start doing it.. Thank you so much for all the effort you give on my problem :)

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis, run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`.  Use the d command to delete partitions 5, 6, then 2, and the n command to create a new extended partition.  It should provide sane defaults that involve it ending before partition 3 starts ( unlike how it is now ).  Then again use the n command to create new logical partitions, with the same start end end sectors you originally listed.  Use the p command to print the table and make sure it looks good, and Finally the w command to write the changes and quit.

Comment: OK, Thanks. Let me go and try this out. I'll post here later how it went. Thanks again.

Comment: I have booted from a live-USB flash, This is what I get when I try to delete the 5th partition.
Not sure what this mean.

Error deleting partition 
/dev/sda5: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sda" "rm 5"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis, you need to use `fdisk` like I said, not the gui disk tool.

Comment: it worked out with `fdisk` now. Thanks a lot.